# SO [joomla tag] vs JSE

Tags: discussion, votes

Have just been looking through a load of question on JSE and on the joomla tag on Stackoverflow and cannot get over the quality of question on SO.

It's getting worse by the day which makes me glad we have a tight community on JSE keeping everything tip top.

### My SO votes

[image]

### My JSE Votes

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly encouraging, though I'd expect to see an increase of low-quality questions as JSE begins to replace SE for Joomla questions.  I'd like to stay on top of things so that it becomes the de facto standard for Joomla Knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Along with some of you, I've started to encourage quality Joomla! questions asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) to be asked at JSE. This helped to the fact that today [key performance indicator **Questions per day** finally made it over **10**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla).

I'd like to share the process/template for inviting/redirecting users which uses some tricks to make invitations fast and effective.

.

#### 1. List latest J! questions.

- At [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), into top-right search box, enter `[joomla*]` then click **Newest**

#### 2. Process questions

2.1. if **question is low quality or not related to Joomla**, add short comment (include `[ask]` text), other improvement hints or also downvote the question.

2.2. at **quality questions without the answer** check OP's profile and if they don't have JSE account yet, add comment

`Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). You might get answers there. Please consider moving your question there (delete it from [so] and paste question text at [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)).`

2.2. **at quality questions already answered** check OP's profile and if they don't have JSE account yet, add comment

`Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future joomla-related questions there.`

2.3. there are other nuances (users with both accounts but not active at JSE, etc.) but I want to keep the answer simple. The merit is to communicate adequately, giving friendly hints.

#### EDIT:

I also suggested a **[simple automation for SO → JSE redirection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247539/intercept-certain-tags-to-lead-users-to-recommended-se-sites)**, what would elliminate need of the above invitation process and greatly help Stack Overflow children like JSE to stand at their own legs. You can support if, if you find it useful.

Comment: Yup good point. I too find myself recommending people ask their question here at JSE. I'm very please at the latest Area51 stats. They're improving drastically

Comment: @Lodder – Yes I know about your activity and I'm glad to see it :) Also your great answers. It is good to keep inviting people until JSE establishes itself better. Please see my [incentive for simple SO → JSE redirection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247539/intercept-certain-tags-to-lead-users-to-recommended-se-sites) which could stop SO from drawing energy from its own children. I guess that people not experienced with sites like JSE do not quite understand what a help it could be.

Answer (score 0):

As you observed yourself, the quality of SO itself has decreased over time.

We need to do our best to keep a good quality of questions and answers, even if it means not making all the users happy.